# How do you fix this: IntegrityError at /restaurants/create? - NOT NULL constraint failed: restaurants_restaurantlocation.name

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make a django developed website which is called MuyPicky. It is a website which allows you to find restaurants and other things based on your pickiness. I am currently making a page for forms which adds Restaurants to the database. As I am doing this I get this error:

```
IntegrityError at /restaurants/create.
NOT NULL constraint failed: restaurants_restaurantlocation.name
```

Is this why I get the error

Here is the forms.py:

```
class RestaurantCreateForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    location = forms.CharField(required = False)
    category = forms.CharField(required = False)
```

The form.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Add Restaurant || {{block.super}} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4  col-md-offset-4">
                    <h1>Add Restaurant</h1>
                    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                        <input title="Title" class="form-control" type="text" name="Title"    placeholder="Title">
                        <br>
                        <input title="Location" class="form-control" type="text" name="Location" placeholder="Location"><br>
                        <input title="Category" class="form-control" type="text" name="Category" placeholder="Category"><br>
                        <!--<input title="Save" class="form-control btn btn-info " type="submit" value="Save" >--><br>
                        <button class="btn btn-success form-control btn-md center-block" type="submit">Save</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The view from views.py:

```
def restaurant_createview(request):
    #if request.method == "GET":
    #   print("get data")
    if request.method == "POST":
        title    = request.POST.get("title") #(request.POST["title"])
        location = request.POST.get("location")
        category = request.POST.get("category")
        obj      = RestaurantLocation.objects.create(
            name     = title,
            location = location, 
            category = category
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/restaurants/")
    template_name = "restaurants/form.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Lastly the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html")), 
  url(r'^restaurants/$', RestaurantListView.as_view()),
  url(r'^restaurants/create/$', restaurant_createview),
  url(r'^restaurants/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', RestaurantDetailView.as_view()),
  url(r'^contact/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contact.html")),
  url(r'^about/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fields have name `Title`, `Location`, `Category` but your Django code is looking for `title`, `location` and `category`. These need to be the same.